# Creating Van der Pol oscillator class with data frames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to recreate this graph:

[image]

... and this table:

[image]

... using this set of equations:

[image]

It has to include these methods:

[image]

> Instructions: Create a class that can be used to simulate Van der Pol oscillators. That class should contain at least the following methods:
>
> - `add_oscillator(self, mu, x0=1, y0=0)`: Add a new oscillator with parameters `mu` initial values `x(0)=x0` (default: `1`) and `y(0)=y0` (default: `0`).
> - `delete_oscillator(self, i)`: Delete the `i-th` oscillator from the list of available oscillators.
> - `getsim_data(self, duration=30.0, dt=0.01)`: Simulate the `N` oscillators previously added to the object (using `add_oscilator`) for the specified `duration` (default: `30s`) and with a sampling step `dt` (default: `0.01s`) and return the simulated data as a pandas `DataFrame` of shape `(duration/dt, N)`. "Simulating" these oscillators mean obtaining `x(t)` by solving the ODE above. This can be done manually using the Euler integration scheme (as seen in previous labs) or using an ODE solver (e.g., `scipy.solve_ivp()` function).
> - `plot(fself, tmin=0.0, tmax=30.0)`: Plot the time course of the different oscillators from `tmin` to `tmax`.
>
> Here is an example of use:

```py
vdp = VanDerPol()
vdp.add_oscillator(1.0)  # oscilator 0
vdp.add_oscillator(3.0)  # oscilator 1
vdp.add_oscillator(2.0)  # oscilator 2
vdp.delete_oscilator(1)
print(vdp.get_sim_data(dt=0.01))
vdp.plot(tmin=10)
```

I am trying to create a Python class to simulate a Van der Pol oscillator using `numpy`, `scipy`, `DataFrame`, and `matplotlib`.

This is my first exposure to coding, so I'm aware my code might be very junky.

I started off by completing the `add_oscillator` and `delete_oscillator` functions. Both seem to work, though I'm unsure if the `new_oscillator` class is the best way to achieve what I did.

I began running into problems in `get_sim_data`. I used information from [this link](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/12/22/van-der-pol/) to get a function working, and then adding the data to a `DataFrame`. The resulting data seems to be wrong, and I'm not sure where the mistake is.

The graphed plot also doesn't look like what I need it to look alike, and the `x-axis` numbers are `0-3000`, instead of `10-30`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```py
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class VanDerPol:
    def __init__(self):
        self.oscillators = []
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()

    def add_oscillator(self, mu, x0=1, y0=0):
        class new_oscillator:
            def __init__(self, mu, x0, y0):
                self.mu = mu
                self.x0 = x0
                self.y0 = y0

            def __str__(self):
                return f"mu={self.mu}, x0={self.x0}, y0={self.y0}"

        self.oscillators.append(new_oscillator(mu, x0, y0))

    def delete_oscillator(self, i):
        self.oscillators.pop(i)

    def get_sim_data(self, duration=30.0, dt=0.01):
        # durations = np.arange(0, duration, dt, dtype=float)
        durations = np.linspace(0, duration, int(duration / dt))
        # df = pd.DataFrame(durations)

        for o in self.oscillators:

            def vdp(t, z):
                x, y = z
                return [y, o.mu * (1 - x**2) * y - x]

            data = solve_ivp(vdp, [0, duration], [o.x0, o.y0], t_eval=durations)
            # df = pd.DataFrame(data.y[0])
            # df = pd.DataFrame()
            df = pd.DataFrame(data.y[0])
            # df[o] = pd.Series(data.y[0])
            # print(data.y[0])
            self.df[o] = df
            # print(self.df)
            print(self.df)

    def plot(self, tmin=0.0, tmax=30.0):
        plt.plot(self.df)


vdp = VanDerPol()
vdp.add_oscillator(1.0)  # oscillator 0
vdp.add_oscillator(3.0)  # oscillator 1
vdp.add_oscillator(2.0)  # oscillator 2
vdp.delete_oscillator(1)
print(vdp.get_sim_data(dt=0.01))
vdp.plot(tmin=10)
```

Comment: You should test small.  Instead of testing all of your code at one time, isolate 2-3 lines, and test those with known inputs/outputs.

Comment: e.g. is solve_ivp doing what you expect?  Is add_oscillator?

Comment: @Him I tested it in small chunks as I was writing it. I know add_oscillator and delete_oscillator both work and get_sim_data produces a result but I don't believe it is correct and I'm guessing the error is in the formula.

Comment: Which line of your code represents "this set of equations"?

Comment: @Him its the vdp formula. the vdp(t,z) and return line. Lines 31 and 33.

Comment: The `vdp` function doesn't look like the equations you provided.  Possibly that's your issue.